# Difficulty with hosting Multilingual Wagtail site on alwaysdata

Tags: django, localization, internationalization, wagtail, wagtail-admin

my wagtail site has two languages English and German
Facing some issues when deploying on alwaysdata.net

I'm using these two apps for the multilingual feature in the INSTALLED_APPS list:

```
"wagtail.locales",
"wagtail.contrib.simple_translation",
```

This is the middleware:

```
"django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware",
```

these are the settings in settings.py:

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = "en-us" 
TIME_ZONE = "UTC" 
USE_I18N = True 
WAGTAIL_I18N_ENABLED = True 
USE_L10N = True 
USE_TZ = True

WAGTAIL_CONTENT_LANGUAGES = LANGUAGES = [ ('en', "English"), ('de', "German") ] 
WAGTAIL_CONTENT_LANGUAGES_FALLBACK = {'default': 'en',}
```

I have the following code in the main urls.py file:

```
urlpatterns += i18n_patterns (
    path("", include(wagtail_urls)),
    prefix_default_language=True,
)
```

The project is running fine locally and also running fine in production server (with DEBUG=TRUE)

My problem is, In Production server when I set DEBUG to False the multilingual features gets messed up.
I have to manually add /en/ or /de/ at the end of the url to see the pages in the browser

for example if I click on the logo (from nav) which has the url set to '/' , it redirects to `mydomain.com` , but it should be `mydomain.com/en/` or `mydomain.com/de/` depending on which language currently selected.

with DEBUG=True it redirects to `mydomain.com/en/` or `mydomain.com/de/` when clicking on the logo(you can say homepage) perfectly.

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Could somebody please guide me through this? I'm happy answer any of your question about the project.